# How can get the bundle item of a bundle product in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a bundle product and I have added 3 bundle items (of type checkboxes) to it through the admin panel. 2 of the bundle item have only one selection in it, while the third one has 7 selections(each of which are simple products).

Now i have a situation in which i need to display the names of simple products that i have added to the third bundle product and not the entire bundle item(default case).I have tried  a lot and i couldn't find a solution for it

Hint: the checkbox default display is defined in the file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/checkbox.phtml and i think we need to do codings here in this file.

please help me guys.. i really need a solution for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... I think I have found a solution for this. I have added bundle item with a name 'LLC' and added simple products as checkboxes.. what i need to do is to display the names of simple products that I have added under the LLC bundle item instead of displaying LLC along with their checkboxes(default case).

The way of displaying checkboxes are defined in the file : 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/checkbox.phtml

so i have defined a function there as like this..

```
<?php 

if($this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle())=="LLC")
{
     $current_product=Mage::registry('current_product');
     echo $this->getpackagedetails($current_product,$this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle()));

 }

 ?>
```

here as you can see, i checked the name of the bundle item is LLC or not. If yes, get the current product to a variable and then i called a function 'getpackagedetails()' which is defined in the block of checkbox which you can find here /app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php. This function passes two arguments: current product and the bundle item name.

Now add our function in to the block file. it is given below.

```
<?php

 public function getpackagedetails($currentproduct,$optid)
 {
        $display="";
        $bundled = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $bundled->load($currentproduct->getId());

        $selectionCollection = $bundled->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
        $bundled->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled), $bundled);

        foreach($selectionCollection as $option)
        {
            $sku=$option->getSku();
            if($optid=="LLC" && $optid==$bistype)
            {
                if(strpos($sku,"llc")!== false)
                {
                    $display.=$option->getName();
                }
            }

        }
        return($display);
  }
```

Here what I have done is i have loaded my current product using the variable $bundled. Then i get all selection type options that i have added to my bundle product to the variable $selectionCollection. In order to seperate options correspond to the LLC bundle item, I have checked whether there is 'llc' string in the sku of each option(all simple product corresponds to the LLC bundle item, i have set 'llc' string in there sku). If yes get there name and store it into the variable $display. then returned the variable.

thats it. now you can see only the simple product name that i have added for the bundle item with name LLC.